# Applying bash variable to mysql insert statements - works for some not others

Tags: mysql, linux, bash

I've been attempting to collate information from my dev CentOS 7 server and dev mysql 8.0 databases and enter them into a separate database/tables to be read by a monitoring dashboard. Currently I'm attempting to retrieve all of the table storage sizes for each db within mysql and enter the data into a separate table.

I've been having an issue when using bash variables to hold the name of a db. For some db names it's worked fine but for others I've had issues, even when using the same syntax.

I've been running the 'TableStorage' function to execute an insert into select statement to populate my TABLE_STORAGE monitoring table (see below)

```
function TableStorage {
    DB1='database1'
    DB2='database2'
    mysql -u $DBA_USER -p$DBA_PASS <<EOF
        INSERT INTO splunk.TABLE_STORAGE (TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, SIZE_MB) SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024)
            FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$DB1' ORDER BY (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) DESC;
        INSERT INTO splunk.TABLE_STORAGE (TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, SIZE_MB) SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024)
            FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = '$DB2' ORDER BY (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) DESC;

        COMMIT;
    EOF
}
```

However, when I run the above function only the table information from 'database1' is inserted into the and not both 'database1' and 'database2'. 
I can confirm that both databases have multiple tables so it's not as if the data isn't present.
Even when I've ran just the insert statement using the function to insert the tables from 'database2' I've still had no luck.
I've also ran both of the above statements manually in mysql and all of the tables are inserted that way, just not when ran in the function.

I've also double checked the following:
-db is present
-tables are present
-bash variables are set
-echo'd entire statement in bash to ensure variables properly populate insert statement (they do)

Really stumped on this one, I can imagine this being a very silly mistake that I've missed. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to use double quotes instead of single quotes: `"$DB1"`.

Comment: Also use prepared statements rather than concatenating strings and risking expanding rogue values containing SQL grammar. (See: https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-prepared-statements.html)

Comment: https://bobby-tables.com/

Comment: With the default heredoc redirection, you must not have any other characters than "EOF" on the terminating line: no leading or trailing spaces.

Answer (score 2):

An example with prepared statements:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TableStorage() {
  [ "$#" -ne 2 ] && return 1 # Two database-name arguments required

  mysql -u "$DBA_USER" -p "$DBA_PASS" <<EOF
    PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'INSERT INTO splunk.TABLE_STORAGE (TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, SIZE_MB) SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024)
    FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @db ORDER BY (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) DESC';

    SET @db="$1";
    EXECUTE stmt1 USING @db;
    SET @db="$2";
    EXECUTE stmt1 USING @db;
    COMMIT;
    DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;
EOF
}

if TableStorage 'database1' 'database2'; then
  echo "TableStorage ok"
else
  echo "Failure to run TableStorage" >&2
fi
```

Alternatively with an arbitrary number of database names:

```sh
#!/usr/bin/env bash

TableStorage() {

  # Block to compose the SQL commands stream
  {
    # Prepare a statement
    echo "PREPARE stmt1 FROM 'INSERT INTO splunk.TABLE_STORAGE (TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, SIZE_MB) SELECT TABLE_SCHEMA, TABLE_NAME, ROUND((DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) / 1024 / 1024) FROM information_schema.TABLES WHERE TABLE_SCHEMA = @db ORDER BY (DATA_LENGTH + INDEX_LENGTH) DESC';"

    # While there is a database name argument
    while [ "$#" -gt 0 ]; do
      # Set SQL variable @db to database name argument $1
      # and execute the prepared statement
      printf 'SET @db="%s";\nEXECUTE stmt1 USING @db;\n' "$1"
      # Shift to next argument $1
      shift
    done
    # Commit the changes
    echo "COMMIT;"
    # Dispose of the prepared statement
    echo "DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt1;"
  } |
    # Pipe the SQL commands to MySQL
    mysql -u "$DBA_USER" -p "$DBA_PASS"
}

if TableStorage 'database1' 'database2'; then
  echo "TableStorage ok"
else
  echo "Failure to run TableStorage" >&2
fi
```

Comment: Thank you that helps, although I'm getting an empty set even when I substitute the DB1/2 variables with the db names. Would you also be able to explain what this does please? I'm new to bash [ "$#" -ne 2 ] && return 1

Comment: @walkerja It returns code 1 when there are not exactly two arguments.  `[ "$#" -ne 2 ]` tests that argument count is not equals to 2. `&& return 1` logical AND return 1.

Comment: Ah thank you, that makes sense. I've taken a closer look and when I return @db within mysql it doesn't return the value of the bash variable just $DB1 instead, hence why no data is being inserted into the table. Any ideas on how to fix that?

Comment: @walkerja I edited my code, try the updated version. Possibly the single-quotes prevented the variable value expansion, but this is really wierd. Are you really using Bash and not some other shell like Zsh?